# How can I check if a form has been opened, and if it has, get the value from the control?

Tags: c#, winforms

So basically, I have a form with a Calendar(frmCalendar) control on it. I have another form that has a DatePicker (frmDatePicker).

frmDatePicker can be opened before frmCalendar would be even created.

What I need to know, is how can I

1. Check if the frmCalendar has been opened.
2. If it has, how would I get the value of the MonthCalendar(mcUserDate) control?

If you need to know the context, the datePicker is to set the current quarterEnd date for Reports, which are created outside the application.

The calendar is used internally in the application.

It's a "nice to have" if the DatePicker would default to the currently quarter date chosen in the application (IF it has been chosen).

**EDIT**

```
      Main Form
      |        \
      |         \
  frmCalendar    frmReports
                    \
                     \
                     frmDatePicker
```

still easy?

Comment: Two different forms in the same application? or two different applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the forms are both in the same application, I would personaly use property's. I would have a formOpened property that returns a bool to check if the form has been opened, and I would have a quarterEndingDate property that would return the DateTime from the datePicker.

i.e. in the main Form:

```
if (frmcalender != null)
    {
        if (frmcalender.formOpened)
            textBox1.Text = frmcalender.quarterEndDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

in frmCalender:

```
public partial class frmCalendar : Form
    {
        bool activated;
        public frmCalendar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            activated = true;
        }

        public bool  formOpened
        {
            get
            {
                return activated;
            }
        }

        public DateTime quarterEndDate
        {
            get 
            {
                return mcUserDate.Value;
            }

            set 
            {
                mcUserDate.Value = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not so sure it's that easy. Please read the edits I've made to better visualize what I'm doing. (Maybe it won't change anything?)

Comment: It should still work. You may have to cascade property's between frmReports and frmDatePicker. Your problem is getting visibility of the state of another form. As long as you have a reference to that form property's are the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this:

1. The form itself keep a global public static variable that points to itself and is initialized when the form is created.  So say frmCalender.Current != null (then it exists), then you'll have to from within frmCalender make whatever control you want access to public/available via properties/whatever.
2. A global form list that is a list of all forms created, that the form places itself in when created.  Similar to (1) for the rest.
3. A component tracker (I currently use this method, it obfuscates every component into its own class wrapper and only subscribes to the components its interested in).  It can then do `Components.Find<componentWrapper>()` and if it exists, gets it and does whatever with it.  Like subscribing to the component's events, etc.

I'm sure there are many more ways, though I find number 1 the easiest, and still use it.